# Animation difference between show and hide with jQuery 1.6.3

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have multiple containers with links, like this:

```
<div class="items" id="first"><a href="item1">item 1</a></div>
```

The containers have a background image and the links are hidden with: `display: none;`

```
$(".items").mouseover(function() {
    $("a", this).show(1500);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("a", this).hide(1500);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/wtZPQ/)

Now the problem is that the text is showing slow, but the place which occupies is taken immedeiatly. How to achieve the oposite - the text to be visible immediately and its place which it occupies to be shown slowly?

Comment: Looks to me like they both are happening slowly, so I don't quite understand your question?  Make the show delay smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wtZPQ/2/

you may also want to display:block to makesure the text doesnt wrap.

Comment: I should have explained a little more. in the css i set the width of the links to 0. Then we use jquery to show() it on hover. Its now shown with a width of 0px. Next we animate the link to a width to get the desired result. Do the opposite on the mouseout

Comment: This works if Milo doesn't need the text to fade in - not really clear what the end result is supposed to be though.

Answer (score 0):

When your `<a>` are hidden, they take up no space on the screen. As soon as they become un-hidden, they suddenly take up space. That is why, in your live example, on hover you immediately see that space open up.

The text has gone from taking up zero space to taking up it's full space. It's not immediately visible because the opacity starts at zero, and only reaches full opacity after 1500 milliseconds. Even at opacity zero, though, it still now exists, taking up space.

So what you're asking isn't really possible. You COULD make your `<a>` absolutely positioned, so they never take up space, then after they fade in completely make the space between your graphics expand, but I'm not sure that's what you're going for....

Answer (score 0):

Oh weird, I tried it in JQuery 1.4.4 and it works correctly, but as shown in your jsfiddle it breaks in 1.6.3.

Anyway, i guessed that it was because an `a` tag default has a `display` style of `inline` which doesn't let you assign width.

You can force it to be `.items a { display:inline-block; }` and then hide them using JQuery:

```
$(".items a").hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wtZPQ/3/